# Create and delete tables in responsive design, Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design

I want that, depending on the width of the browser, tables should be created or deleted.

In CSS, you can use something like: `@media (min-width: 767px), whereas css-settings change, after width passes 767px. Is there something similar for ruby on rails? For example:

In my book/view.html.erb there is a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @book.title %></td>
    <td><%= @book.genre %></td>
    <td><%= @book.desc %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is, that, after width gets smaller than 767px, it should look like this:

```
Title: <br>
<%= @book.title %><br>
Genre: <br>
<%= @book.genre %>
Description:
<%= @book.desc %>
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something similar for ruby on rails

Yes, it's called [`browser`](https://github.com/fnando/browser) - a gem:

*[Browser] adds a helper method called `browser`, that inspects your current user agent:*

```
#app/views/controller/your_view.html.erb
<% if browser.tablet? || browser.mobile? %>
   ... do something ...
<% end %>
```

--

The *problem* with this, however, is that it only works when you render the page.

`CSS Media queries` adapt when the page changes dimension, meaning that if you decide to resize the app on your desktop, the CSS will immediately adapt.

`Rails` compiles code based on an HTTP request, meaning that it cannot "change" as CSS does. Whilst this shouldn't be a problem for tablets etc, it may cause issues for desktops.

---

## Solution

> What I want is, that, after width gets smaller than 767px, it should look like this

```
<% if browser.mobile? %>

   Title: <br>
     <%= @book.title %><br>
   Genre: <br>
     <%= @book.genre %>
   Description:
     <%= @book.desc %>

<% else %>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= @book.title %></td>
        <td><%= @book.genre %></td>
        <td><%= @book.desc %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

<% end %>
```

A completely CSS solution (*highly* recommended):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .big   { display: none; }
   .small { display: block; }
}

#app/view
<%= content_tag :div, class: "big" do %>
   <table>
     <tr>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Genre</th>
         <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><%= @book.title %></td>
         <td><%= @book.genre %></td>
         <td><%= @book.desc %></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
<% end %>
<%= content_tag :div, class: "small" do %>
   Title: <br>
     <%= @book.title %><br>
   Genre: <br>
     <%= @book.genre %>
   Description:
     <%= @book.desc %>       
<% end %>
```

Comment: Works! Thank you so much! Just two questions: Is this common practice? What do I need to google, to find more informations? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What is common practice? `browser` gem or CSS?

Comment: Well content tag is just rails way of adding a div. Class styling is a standard of HTML - you should use it with the media queries... the best place to look would be [`css-tricks.com`](http://css-tricks.com) although by far the best way is to just experiment with stuff